# Why is query slow but procedure fast on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Why is it that if I run my query as a parameterized procedure it runs 10 times faster then if I run it directly as a parameterized query?

I'm using the exact same query in both cases, and it doesn't matter if I'm calling from  Management Studio or an SqlCommand from code.

EDIT: The execution plan looks different.  So, why? I'm calling it with EXACTLY the same set of parameters.

EDIT: After more testing it seems the 10x slowdown only occurs when running the parameterized query from SQL Management Studio.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One thing I've seen recently is that if you set up the query parameters wrong it can cause major problems.

For example, say you have a parameter for an indexed varchar column and set it up from .Net using the SqlCommand's `AddWithValue()` method.  You're in for a world of hurt with this scenario.  .Net uses unicode strings and will set up your parameter as an nvarchar rather than varchar. Now sql server won't be able to use your index, and you'll see a significant performance penalty.

Comment: I've also recently seen this behaviour.  Can cause some major performance problems.

Comment: @Kibbee: I think it was your comments in another SO question a month or two ago that turned me on to investigating the behavior.  Thankfully I never use AddWithValue anyway and always specify the parameter type explicitly, so it wasn't an issue in any of my older code.

Answer (score 4):

Find out if they are using the same execution plan is to display it when running. Use "include actual execution plan" in management studio and see what is the difference.

Comment: you beat me to the answer - I was typing when your answer arrived.

Answer (score 3):

The connection-level settings can be critical in some cases, especially `ANSI NULLS`, `CONCAT NULL YIELDS NULL`, etc. In particular, if you have **calculated** persisted indexed columns (including promoted "xml" columns), then it won't trust the pre-calculated, index value if the settings aren't compatible, and will recalculate for each row (i.e. table scan instead of index seek).

Answer (score 2):

Parameterized queries have a lot of [advantages](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/database/database-tip-use-parameterized-queries.html), including often a hefty performance increases.

- Caching of queries
- String Concatenation problems minimized
- addressing SQL injection
- Data does not have to be converted to a string before processing

Comment: "query with parameters" would be a parameterized query, wouldn't it?

Comment: From the server's perspective, no. The parameterization is happening on the client side if you make it a query with parameters.  That is assuming you're talking about making a query with parameters in ADO/ADO.net.

Comment: sorry my mistake, I haven't even tested the sql injection query method.

Answer (score 1):

Parameter sniffing may be affecting the stored procedure performance.

http://omnibuzz-sql.blogspot.com/2006/11/parameter-sniffing-stored-procedures.html

Answer (score -1):

Stored procedures can run faster because the execution plan is cached by sql server.

But 10 times performance is suspicious.
Does it run the same the First time after you've cleared the stored execution plans?  You can use these commands to clear the cache.  But they clear the whole servers cache so do it only on development servers.

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB (<dbid>)
```

Are you running these directly on the SQL server to eliminate any network I/O from the performance testing?

My guess is that it is running slowly the first time, then once it is cached it is running faster.

Comment: Aren't all queries cached in v. 2005 and above?

Comment: Yes, parameterized queries are cached in the same way as sprocs.